# How to call method in other class from a static class

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I have absolutely no experience with OOP. I'm first year in college and my internship project requires that I do a form application in C#.

I have two classes, a form class Form and a static class "Port_Com" where I wrote the functions that communicate with a Raspberry.

Here's the method I want to call from my second class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    {...}
    public void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + ">" + message);
        }
}
```

My second class:

```
public class Port_Com
{
    private static void Main()
    {
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```

Basically I want to display a log in my rich text box.

Comment: No, you cannot call a non-static method from a static class without an instance

Comment: I get the impression you need to new up Form1 to show it at some stage, and then you would have an instance and don't need to make a static call to it.

Comment: @sujithkarivelil And how would setting up an instance work in my case?

Comment: @CRice I did this: `public class Port_Com
{
    private static void Main()
    {
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.WriteLine("test");
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Main` entry point static method usually creates a main form like:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

You need to save `Form1` object somewhere, then you can call its methods like:

```
var mainForm = new Form1();
Application.Run(mainForm );
...
mainForm.WriteLine("Hello!");
```

Also it's better to refactor log method to allow to call it from another thread as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls), because window' controls must be updated in UI thread only. As this is about `COM` port communication, it most probably will be called from background thread as well. Like:

```
public void WriteLine(string message)
{
    if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var d = new SafeCallDelegate(WriteLine);
        Invoke(d, new object[] { message });
    }
    else
    {
        this.richTextBox1.AppendText(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is basically what I needed. Sorry for the dumb question, I'm new to both C# and OOP but the application looks nice now :) Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should either *find* `Form1` instance or *create* it and only then, call the method:

```
 using System.Linq;
 ... 
 //TODO: Main is a specific name (entry point of the exe), I suggest renaming it
 private static void Main() {
    // Do we have opened Form1? 
    Form1 form = Application
      .OpenForms        // from all opened forms
      .OfType<Form1>()  // we want just Form1 instances
      .LastOrDefault(); // If we have several, let's take the last one

    // Comment out this fragment if you don't want to create it
    if (null == form) { 
      // No open Form1 forms found
      form = new Form1(); // Let's create Form1 instance manually
      form.Show();        // And Show it
    }
    else {
      // form has been found; but you may want

      // Resore it if it's minimized 
      if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
      // Bring it to front
      form.BringToFront();
      // Set keyboard focus on it 
      if (form.CanFocus)
        form.Focus(); 
    }

    // We have a form to work with, we are ready to call the method
    if (null != form)
      form.WriteLine("Hello World!");  
    else { // No Form1 intance has been found; we can't call WriteLine
      //TODO: put relevant code here
    }             
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call a non static function, without a instance. When a function is non static, you need a instance of the class. 
To call your Form Class, you need to do this:

```
From1 frm = new Form1();
frm.WriteLine("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define a static event in your Port_Com class. When your form is ready, register the event. If Port_Com has something to tell form to show, trigger the event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    void Form_Load()
    {
        Port_Com.NewMessage += msg=> 
        {
            // call WriteLine on UI thread
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
                this.WriteLine(msg);
            }));
        };
    }
    {...}
    public void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + ">" + message);
        }
}

public class Port_Com
{
    public static event Action<string> NewMessage;
    private static void Main()
    {
        //I want to call the method from here
        NewMessage?.Invoke("Message to Show");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends one what state your application is in...
I assume you have an running WinForms Application with atleast one open Form.
Then you could use `Application.OpenForms` to search for your Form an call the methode
e.g.

```
Form1 instance = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Single();
instance.WriteLine(...);
```